Doubt in Kleppner classical mechanics chapter 1

So I know that I can approach it by first finding $H_1$ which is height till time $T_A$ and then I can find Height till B measured from origin $H_1= \frac{1}{2} g(T_A)^2$ and then $H_2= \frac{1}{2} g(T_B)^2$ and $H_2-H_1=h$ then $g=2h/((T_A)^2-(T_B)^2)$. Is there any flaw in my reasoning? Can anyone provide a hint.

Since you only asked for a hint, I marked the full answer as a spoiler, which you can then read at will.

Assume the maximal height is at horizontal line $C$. At this point, the body has no velocity. By symmetry, the trajectory from $C$ to $A$ takes time $T_A/2$, the trajectory from $C$ to $B$ takes time $T_B/2$.
The respective distances are (usual equation of motion)

$$\overline{CA} \enspace = \enspace \frac{g}{2} \Big( \frac{T_A}{2} \Big)^2 \enspace = \enspace  \frac{g}{8} T_A^2$$
and
$$\overline{CB} \enspace = \enspace  \frac{g}{2} \Big( \frac{T_B}{2} \Big)^2 \enspace = \enspace  \frac{g}{8} T_B^2$$

This implies that the height $h$ may be written as

$$h \enspace = \enspace  \overline{CA} - \overline{CB} \enspace = \enspace \frac{g}{8} \big( T_A^2 - T_B^2 \big)$$

Which finally gives the result
$$ \boxed{g \enspace = \enspace  \frac{8h}{T_A^2 - T_B^2}}$$
